# EventAggregation Pattern in backend systems

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, decoupling, eventaggregator

I want to take advantage of the powerful [`EventAggregator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) pattern for non-WPF backend systems written in C#.

**A.** Is that even a good idea? Is there a specific reason why this is implemented mostly by frontend frameworks?

**B.** If it is, does anyone know a framework (Not Prism obviously) that supports that or can provide some kind of skeleton I can work with?

Comment: Do you use dependency injection?

Comment: @Ric.Net Yes I use [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the breaking down of the Prism, I was able to only use the [PubSubEvents](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.PubSubEvents/) library. All I had to do is to add a MEF wrapper class with `Export` and `PartCreationPolicy` attributes

```
[Export(typeof(IEventAggregator))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class MefEventAggregator : EventAggregator
{
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. And don't forget that MEF exports dependencies as shared by default. If you are going to create ViewModels through the IoC beware of that.

Answer (score 2):

EventAggregator is a general-purpose pattern. It is an abstracted static bus for publishing events and subscribing for them. Nothing else, in essense. There is no restrictions on using it for frontends only.

You can find an implementation of that pattern in Caliburn.Micro framework, for example.

One more point.
Consider that sometimes it occurs that EventAggregator hides dependencies of objects. It's up to you to decide whether it is a good idea, or not.

Comment: That is what I thought also I just found it kind of weird that all the implementations of that pattern are in UI frameworks (including Caliburn.Micro)

Comment: Nothing special, you can use it freely where you feel it suits your requirements.